# Purpose of HTML button?

Tags: javascript, html, button

What was the intended purpose of the HTML `<input type="button">` element, taking into account that Javascript appeared after HTML (hence making me doubt that JS was the intended purpose)?

Comment: what does javascript have to do with it?  I'm pretty sure it's there for semantic/aesthetic reasons.

Comment: @thescientist: Well, nothing happens when you click it. So what was the point of having it?

Comment: Perhaps, Java Applets had something to do with it?

Comment: Not just javascript, but any client-side scripting language. HTML and W3C DOM APIs don't care what the scripting language is (though of course javascript is the most popular now).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure but, if I remember correctly, `<input type="button">` has been added with HTML4.0. Its first draft was from 1997, so 2 years later ECMAScript. So probably is has been introduced exactly for JS purposes.

Take a look to these links provided in comments by Felix Kling:

- [reference to HTML3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#fields) (no `type=button` listed)
- [changes from HTML3 and HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/changes.html#h-A.3.9)

Comment: As per [this article](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/2001/04/06/js_history.html), ECMAScript came later, but yes, JavaScript came in 1995.

Comment: And [a reference to HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#fields), where `type="button"` is not listed (needles to say that `<button>` does not exist either).

Comment: [Another interesting link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/changes.html#h-A.3.9) (changes between HTML 4 and HTML 3) where it says: *The BUTTON element and INPUT with type set to "button" can be used in combination with [scripts](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html) to create richer forms.* So yes, they have been introduced for exactly this purpose.

Comment: @Felix that really should be an answer!

Comment: @Renesis: I see it more as supporting facts to this answer ;) But thanks.

Comment: @Jack: Maybe you can add these links (and the quote) to your answer.

Comment: @Felix - ECMAScript came later, but JavaScript, JScript and VBScript (in a browser) came well before ECMAScript.

Comment: It's essentially what you should be using instead of a hyperlink to add in-page functionality (where you don't have an actual link but are just using the a tag to provide an affordance for clicking)

Answer (score 0):

They only make sense with javascript, otherwise they wont do much in a form.  is supported since HTML4 in Netscape 2.x and Internet Explorer 3.x. Netscape Navigator had javascript support since version 2.0 (1995), so yes, they have been around since the same time that javascript was supported and are useless without js. 
My guess is that they included it so your forms and fields can get a uniform look & feel.

Answer (score -4):

Well, according to the spec
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

> Buttons created with the BUTTON element function just like buttons
>   created with the INPUT element, but they offer richer rendering
>   possibilities: the BUTTON element may have content. For example, a
>   BUTTON element that contains an image functions like and may resemble
>   an INPUT element whose type is set to "image", but the BUTTON element
>   type allows content.
>
> Visual user agents may render BUTTON buttons with relief and an up/down motion when clicked, while they may render INPUT buttons as
>   "flat" images.

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question...?

Comment: `<input type="button" /> !== <button>Button</button>`

Comment: actually that paragraph discusses the <button> element, not the <input type="button"> OP mentioned....

Comment: wow, now who's the fool... I might almost not delete my answer because of this... :p

Comment: Ah, and this is why w3fools (and most others) hates w3schools. They try to make the name sound similar...

Comment: nice comeback.... it could be just be said if the w3c has a problem with it, they're big boys and could do something about it on their own.  I challenge anyone to find a fool proof reference out there anywhere.  People take on w3schools like it's marketing itself as gospel when it's really just a simple, basic reference.  Besides, who only uses one source when researching anything anyway?

Comment: Sounds good in theory, but, especially for those new to web programming, it's easy to think of an officious looking source as definitive. Not to mention w3schools is often the first result in any search :/. Still laughing about my own confusion.

Comment: it happens.  look at my answer!  :D

Comment: to the downvoters.. yeah we get it, it was the wrong answer.  no need to be 'cool' about it!  ....